# Error al convertir String a datetime Python

Tags: python, jupyter, dataset, pyspark

Hola quiero convertir la columna "Date" de mi dataset en Datetime

```
covid.show(5)

+--------+
|    Date|
+--------+
|3-1-2020|
|3-2-2020|
|3-2-2020|
|3-2-2020|
|3-3-2020|
+--------+

covid.printSchema()

root
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true
```

Pongo este codigo para poder convertirlo

```
covid['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid['Date'], format='%y%m%d')
```

Pero me sale este error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11776\4191801137.py in <module>
----> 1 covid['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid['Date'], format='%y%m%d')

~\anaconda3\envs\bigdata\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    880                 # error: Too many arguments for "tz_localize" of "NaTType"
    881                 result = result.tz_localize(tz)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 882     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
    883         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    884         if not cache_array.empty:

~\anaconda3\envs\bigdata\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\generic.py in _check(cls, inst)
     43     @classmethod  # type: ignore[misc]
     44     def _check(cls, inst) -> bool:
---> 45         return getattr(inst, attr, "_typ") in comp
     46 
     47     dct = {"__instancecheck__": _check, "__subclasscheck__": _check}

C:\ApacheSpark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\column.py in __nonzero__(self)
    905 
    906     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 907         raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
    908                          "'~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.")
    909     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Comment: Acabe de agregar una respuesta pero veo segun la que dio el usuario @Osaskoh no sera de ayuda, ¿podria suministrar mas info de su dataframe?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Podrías agregar más información a tu pregunta? ¿Qué es lo que haces con el `dataframe` antes de intentar convertir las fechas? ¿Estas generando la columna `Date` o viene directamente de tus datos? Por favor agrega algunas líneas de tu `dataframe` y el código mínimo para reproducir el error. El único error que veo en este momento es que estás configurando mal el formato, ese argumento indica el formato actual de la columna, no el formato de salida.

Answer (score 0):

se poco de python pero intenta

```
covid['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid['Date'], format='%d%m%y')
```

en lugar de el que tienes por que las fechas que quieres convertir están en formato

`[DD-MM-YYYY]`  y tu quieres convertirla a formato `[YYYY-MM-DD]`

Comment: No, aun me sale el mismo error, igual gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El formato que estas usando es por defecto, intenta usar este formato.

```
covid = {
    'Date' : ['3-1-2020', '3-2-2020', '3-2-2020']
}
covid = pd.DataFrame(covid)
print(covid)
print(covid.dtypes)
print('______________________')
covid['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid['Date'], format="%d-%m-%Y")
print(covid)
print(covid.dtypes)
```

**El resultado es:**

```
       Date
0  3-1-2020
1  3-2-2020
2  3-2-2020
Date    object
dtype: object
______________________
        Date
0 2020-01-03
1 2020-02-03
2 2020-02-03
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```